# Replace text in a pandas dataframe column with regex

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a dataframe with two columns:  "Name" and "Score and comment".

Each value in the "Score and comment" column will either start with one of the following 3 scenarios:

- A number of 0-999 and nothing else
- A number of 0-999, followed by a string of text
- A string

I want to change the value of the "Score and comment" column so that:

- If it starts with a number, delete all text AFTER the number, but leave the number in place.  Numbers will be in the range of 1-999 but no higher.
- If there is no number, then replace all text with '0'
- If there is just a number, leave that alone.

I have tried looking at regular expressions but can't get my head round whether I'm approaching this from the wrong angle.

I have tried myDataFrame.replace('[0-9]{1,3}\s*', '') but the closest I can get is for it to match the first 3 characters if they are numeric and get rid of those.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good usecase for [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) which uses regex and leaves behind only the matching group. For instance:

```
>>> x = pd.Series(["100 some text", "1", "123", "text that should be 0"])
>>> x.str.extract(r'(^[0-9]{1,3})').fillna(0)
     0
0  100
1    1
2  123
3    0
```

So on the assumption that you don't need to worry about numbers that are not 0-999 you could do:

```
myDataFrame["Score and comment"].str.extract(r'(^[0-9]{1,3})').fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I put some sample data in a csv file that looks like this:

```
Name,Score and comment
Amun,123 this is cool
mirjam,23 this is nice
munkel,2 that's just amazing
punkel,this is funny
Rolf,123
Rolf,2
Mirjam2,17
Mirjaa,das ist gut
```

then I ran the following code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv("/filepath/sample_data.txt")
    
    score = df["Score and comment"]
    #here, you first convert the cells that contain only numbers,
    #then, you delete the strings after the numbers in the mixed cells
    #and finally, you set the cells containing only strings to 0 
    for i in range(0,len(score)):
       try:
           score[i] = int(score[i])
       except:
           try:
               score[i] = score[i].split(" ")[0]
               score[i] = int(score[i])
           except:
               score[i] = 0   
    
    #save the file to a new csv
    df.to_csv("/filepath/sample_data_convertet.txt", index = False)
```

The output was the following:

```
Name,Score and comment
Amun,123
mirjam,23
munkel,2
punkel,0
Rolf,123
Rolf,2
Mirjam2,17
Mirjaa,0
```

It worked fine for me :-) I hope this helps